# Right CSS file not loaded, another somewhere else's loaded

Tags: php, html, css, cpanel

I have a little problem with my website. My CSS file located in `css/style.css` who is empty doesn't load when in my `index.php` located in `public_html` on cPanel loads.

I'm using a link that I've put:

```
link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css'
```

in head section but it doesn't load this one, instead it does load one from http://www.cssreset.com/ by Eric Meyer as you can see here while my `style.css` located in `css/style.css` is actually empty. http://theolt.getheb.com/css/style.css.

Can someone help me guys? I have absolutely no idea of why it does this, i'm using cPanel hosted on my friend's website getheb.com and even him doesn't know why it does this.

Comment: I see the CSS reset code in http://theolt.getheb.com/css/style.css

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, basically, my style.css located in css/style.css is actually empty but it take the code directly from the cssreset.com website without loading style.css located in css/style.css using this code in the index.php: link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css'

Comment: Do you have a link to the site in question or can you show some more code from your index.php showing how the site is being rendered?
EDIT: Looks like your site at theold.getheb.com is loading correctly the css looks fine, if something is wrong it looks like some php isn't executing casing your content not to show.

Comment: Yes, here's the link to the actual content of the index.php file located in public_html: http://theolt.getheb.com/code/index.php.txt and the style.css actual file in css folder: http://theolt.getheb.com/code/css/style.css.txt . As you can see, thing are not right. it's not how it should look on the website main page.

Comment: Try putting a leading `/` on the href for your css file.

Comment: Still nothing... It's like if a style from somewhere else that i didn't have put in my index.php have took over my css/style.css from www.cssreset.com. I even tried contacting them, but got no reply yet. I even tried removing the css folder with the style.css, but it's still like if the folder with the file was still here. Kinda like invisible folders and files. Must be related to some saved files somewhere but not sure if it's about the cache or just a bug with cPanel.

Comment: did you specify a base href?

Comment: A base href? What is it exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably the **cache** on the web servers. In my experience I was making changes to my site using localhost and as I transfer it to the web it doesn't make any changes. The problem was it takes 12 hours for the web servers to propagate the new file. So maybe you should try to contact the hosting site and check if it's about the **cache**. When you **delete** a file then the file is still running on the **live site** then the problem is really the **cache**.

Comment: Hi it's finally me, sorry i forgot to reply here. Finally it wasn't the cache, but just a bug between cPanel from monhebergeur.net and my website. But i'm now using my own VPS so there is no bugs anymore.